Create "path" to "dotted" variable such as "a.b.c.d.e.f"
It is simple to create a variable such as "a", but as soon as I want to create "a.b", I need to know that "a" exists first, I'm trying to create a function such as "function SetPathedVariable(DottedName, Value)".
In the console I have tried  to check and create things like "['a.b']" "['a']['b']" (and many other variations), sometimes preceded by "window" as they are global variables, so far nothing I have tried works.
To make global variables easier to manage and recognise I'm creating ONE global variable and grouping variables as required, for example this is the sort of thing I currently have to do first:
var GlobalVarJs = {};
    GlobalVarJs.BtnHelp = {}; 

I want to remove the above initialization and if the first global variable is "GlobalVarJs.BtnHelp.SomeVariable" then I want it set and after creating the two above levels by executing:
SetPathedVariable("GlobalVarJs.BtnHelp.SomeVariable", "SomeValue")"

Any help appreciated, I don't know enough Javascript to work it out yet.
Using eval() it would have been easy but I've been avoiding that (probably for no good reason).  People talk about injection but is that a problem for information that doesn't come from user input? Most people are very vague in their statements on the security issues.

Lodash solved it for you: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set "If a portion of path doesn't exist, it's created" Seems like it's exactly what you want.

@MisterJojo - what if you later want to add to a.b.c.g - as much as I like one liners, I don't think that will work

Lodash solved it for you: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set "If a portion of path doesn't exist, it's created" Seems like it's exactly what you want.


const GlobalVarJs = {};

_.set(GlobalVarJs, 'a.b.c.d.e', 123);

console.log(GlobalVarJs);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>




I'd rather not include yet another library for a single issue so I tried looking at the indicated duplicate but I'm asking a different question so I don't think mine is a duplicate, it creates a path so it is a partial answer at best.
I also can't work it out and I would prefer an understandable answer so I may just use eval(), but the duplicate's code doesn't seem to work (at least my modified version), jfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/dbareis/watkrcsx/4/

@DennisBareis Lodash is open source and well structured. If you don't want to import the whole library, you can easily pick the parts that are interesting for you. I recommend using a library for this. The code is rather complex and it's easy to forget a special case. If you don't want to use a library, you should write it in the question. But you also shouldn't modify a question that's answered in a way that would invalidate a valid answer.

@DennisBareis Minified and zipped core Lodash has 4kB. I wouldn't waste any time to save 4kB. If you use a bundler with tree shaking, it will remove most of the library in the build step.

After a quick look "bundler with tree shaking" looks interesting but I'm guess it would be hard to use with WordPress.
As it is not hard to create this function with eval() and I fully understand how it works and can debug it if required I will use that.
It is too long for these comments, see my  jfiddle code for anyone who needs it.

You should read Never use direct eval()! Security is only one point. Here starts the code for _.set: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/main/src/set.ts

Thanks for the eval() link, it confirms that at least in my case eval() is not as a security issue, and mainly a performance one which I already knew. Unfortunately "set() requires "baseSet" which requires blah and down the rabbit hole we go.

@DennisBareis On Stack Overflow we're looking for clean, maintainable, good solution, not for dirty hacks with security and/or performance issues. Even if your answer works for you, it's not how professional programmers work. That's why you can expect downvotes if you post you solution as answer. As far as I can remember, every answer containing eval was downvotes because it wouldn't pass any code review in a serious company. If you want garbage code, Stack Overflow is usually the wrong place.

Well I'd argue that my code is clean and understandable and therefore maintainable, it poses no security risks and suffers slightly in performance, no one has shown me how I can get a function that doesn't use eval().  When I work out how that can be done (given I'm getting little help here) I will replace that easily maintainable function.
From my experience most of the code posted (not in this post) is single line and very cryptic by someone who is trying to get the character count to as close to zero as possible, and therefore not maintainable and' I'd argue those are the dirty hacks.

@DennisBareis You got the option to use library. You got the option to copy a handful of functions of this library if you don't want the whole library. You can write yiurour own code inspired by this library. At the top is a link with a similar question (slashes instead of dots). The answers looked cleaned clean, not cryptic . All of this is better than eval.

The "duplicate" is not a duplicate as it uses "lodash" and converts "/" to "dots.  Apart from this what part of "Any help appreciated, I don't know enough Javascript to work it out yet." wasn't understood?
Does Javascript have a insert child property API of some type?  That is what I'm currently googling but most of the answers refer to the DOM.

@DennisBareis Replace the slashes with dots and remove the first dot and /root/library/Folder1/Document becomes root.library.Folder1.Document. Do you see now, why this is a duplicate? Stack Overflow is platform for programmers and programmers modify existing solution to their requirements. What is an "insert child property API"? What is a child property?
